# Laravel - Route::post doesn't ask login

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

In my main page I have a form and I just load the data if the user was authenticate. What happen is that i'm submitting the form via ajax and when the user is not authenticated it gives an error in console.

It should ask login, and not and I don't know why.

This is how I sent the data:

```
var formData = $('#newLetter').serialize();
  var url = '/backend/newLetter/';
  $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      cache: false,
      //dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          if (typeof data.error === 'undefined') {
              console.log('SUCCESS: ' + data.success);
              window.location.href = "/backend/user-letter";
          } else {
              console.log('ERRORS: ' + data.error);
          }
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          // Handle errors here
          console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
      },
      complete: function () {

      }
  });
```

My route:

```
Auth::routes();    
Route::post('/backend/newLetter', 'HomeController@newLetter');
```

What I want is when user is not authenticated, it goes to login, after login process the form.

How can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: As you are making ajax call so it won't go to login page. Laravel will automatically handle it if you stop using ajax. Or you will have to redirect to login page manually on `ajax error method`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect your users to login page if they are not authenticated, first you need to protect your route using auth middleware.

```
Route::post('/backend/newLetter', 'HomeController@newLetter')->middleware('auth');
```

This will result in a redirect to login page for http requests and a 401 Unauthenticated error for ajax requests. As you're using ajax request, you will get a 401 Unauthenticated error, so you need to redirect users back to login page. Add the following scripts to your view to handle it:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
    if (exception == 'Unauthorized') {
        window.location = 'http://yourdomain.com/login';            
    }
});
```

After login, they will redirect back to the last page they have visited.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if your user is logged in in your HomeController :

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    // The user is logged in, return your response...
}else{
    // The user is not, return a json error to handle with JS
    // Here you can temporary store the request to execute after login
}
```

If you don't need Ajax, you can add the Auth middleware to your route, and it will automatically redirect to login if the user is not authenticated. Laravel redirects automatically to the initial url after login, but I don't know the behaviour with POST requests, it may be a good starting point if you wish to stop using Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use middleware to make sure the user is authenticated. It looks like you've set up the auth system correctly, now you just need to protect your routes with that middleware. The documentation explains how to do this:

[Protecting Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#protecting-routes)

So after reading that, you should understand that your route declaration should be:

```
Route::post('/backend/newLetter', 'HomeController@newLetter')->middleware('auth');
```

A more common way to do this is to make a route group, so that you don't have to use `->middleware('auth')` every time:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    // Define protected routes here
});
```